# Chat with python thread. Program do not exit

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, chat

I'm studying python building a chat with socket and thread. The problem is that my client does not properly exist when I execute  or  or type "/quit". The program ends, but the prompt does not back. I think my thread is running yet.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import socket
from threading import Thread

class Client(Thread):
    def __init__(self, server_host, server_port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.server_host = server_host
        self.server_port = server_port

    def run(self):
        self.connect()
        self.accepting = True
        self.rec_message()

    def connect(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((self.server_host, self.server_port))
        print 'Conectado ao servidor %s:%s' % (self.server_host, self.server_port)

    def close(self):
        print 'Fechar'
        self.sock.close()
        self.accepting = False

    def send_message(self, msg):
        self.sock.sendall(msg)

    def rec_message(self):
        while self.accepting:
            print self.sock.recv(1024)



# Criar objeto da classe cliente
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 38267
client = Client(HOST, PORT)
client.start()

msg = raw_input()
while msg <> '/quit':
    client.send_message(msg)
    msg = raw_input()

client.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried putting some print statement just before `client.close()` to check if your loop is exiting properly?

Comment: I think you got threading wrong. When you create a `Client` class you run it in a different thread. Calling send `send_message` and `close` from your module doesn't trigger those methods in the same thread the client is running. You should use a queue in order to communicate with your client.

Comment: Yes, client.close() is executed.

Comment: @DoronCohen, it's broken my mind. Methods outside class (client.send_message(msg)) and inside (self.connect()) are dealing with two different Threads? I think it's not true. But I can be wrong...

Comment: I solve this using "client.daemon = True" before start the Thread. It means that when the program terminates, It kill all threads. But I don't know if it is the best solution. And I don't know if I'm using socket and thread properly.

Comment: @VictorVidigalRibeiro Now Im not sure either. Better check it by printing thread id in each class method (including init).